# Does negative z-index affect performance or compatibility?

Tags: html, css, canvas, webgl, z-index

I have a web application where I need to show a 3D model using webGl in the background then showing different stuff on top of it.

All is working VERY fine in **firefox** except in **chrome** where I need to give the canvas a negative value for the z-index rule in CSS.

So I would say I need one of two things:

- If I fix this issue giving a negative z-index to the canvas, will this cause any harm on to my application in any of the browsers *(in both desktop and mobile)*
- Could anybody guess why its not working in **Chrome** *(perhaps from a previous experince)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked the question differently a second time and I got my answer, for more details check out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19830934/1358670