# Does negative z-index have any side effects

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, cross-platform

I've been searching for a while for an answer to my question:

> ***Does negative z-index have any side effects***

And I've already asked before here: [Does negative z-index affect performance or compatibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19770906/1358670) but it doesn't get enough attention (may be because I mixed things a little bit)

And I wanted to try and asked in a other way.

I am developing a web application for cross platforms (different browsers, devices), and sometimes I am in need to use a negative value for the z-index property, but I'm afraid if it can have any side effects on any/some browser and break the compatibility.

I hope I made the question clear :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Negative values are fine after Chrome 1.0, FireFox 3.0, IE 4.0, Opera 4.0, Safari 1.0.  So basically if you don't live in 2000 you should be fine using negative z-indices.  MDN doesn't seem to have any data for mobile devices though, but I would imagine since it's in the spec that most mobile browsers will also be fine.

[Browser support of negative z-index values (CSS 2.1) according to the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Thanks Mash for the quick answer, I'll wait a bit if no better answers come (since I'm most interested in mobile support), I'll gladly accept :)

Comment: Good job to have spotted the line on the MDN page.